# My function with *args remake only first argument python, but i need them all to be remaked

Tags: python, function, args

I need to write a decorator, which delete whitespaces from the start and end of the strigs, which are given like an arguments of another function. At first i tried to write just a function which use `strip`, but it remakes only first given arg, when i need them all. `join` needed because without it function returns tuple.

```
def NewFunc(*strings):
    newstr = ' '.join([str(x) for x in strings])
    return newstr.strip()

print(NewFunc('         Anti   ', '     hype   ', '   ajou!   '))
```

and it returns: `Anti         hype       ajou!`

when i need:`Anti hype ajou!`

what to change?

Comment: You need to strip each element, within the list comprehension.

Comment: `' '.join([str(x).strip() for x in strings])` should do, and remove the other `strip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strip` only removes leading and trailing whitespace, and you are only `strip`ping the final result. You must `strip` each element before `join`ing them, and this can be done in the list comprehension:

```
def NewFunc(*strings):
    newstr = ' '.join([str(x).strip() for x in strings])
    return newstr
```

The `str(x)` is a bit unnecessary, but I don't know, maybe you are going to pass in `int`s or something.